# Flutter Laravel Api returns no response

Tags: flutter

i have a getx controller where i created a register user function, but when i call it from the register ui nothing seems to happen

```
RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url + 'register');
Future registerUser(name, email, password) async {
try {
  // Register user
  isLoading.value = true;
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    }),
  );
  isLoading.value = false;
  final res = json.decode(response.body);
  if (res['success'] == true) {
    print(res);
  } else {
    print(res);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}
```

Comment: sometimes in backend developer use formdata, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
if you can show error or api endpoint it will be easy to get where you stuck!

Comment: That's the issue I wrote the backend and it worked well, no error from there .. written in Laravel

Comment: so you miss in flutter.  can it be content-type or passing wrong end point.
for that can you show api response in postman ?

Comment: Could it be wrong endpoint cause the flutter emulator was not connecting to 127.0.0.1 before

Comment: for emulator. use http://10.0.2.2:3000/

after ':' number is your server port

Comment: Like this? var url = 'http://10.0.0.2:8000/api/';

Comment: I did that now if i click on signup it takes like 2-3 min and returns this 
I/flutter ( 5801): SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 44239

Comment: your server is running?. please check on postman first

Comment: Yes it is running